# Spring Boot Security Logout Does Not Invalidate Session

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

My enhanced Pet Clinic application requires security.

Currently the logout functionality does not seem to work. I have a GET version (simple link) and a POST version (hidden form submitted by a link).

After login, whichever method I use to log out, once I try to log in again, the new login is not allowed.

I believe this is linked to this section:

```
.sessionManagement()
    .maximumSessions(1)
    .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
    .expiredUrl("/login?expired")
```

but I thought that this section:

```
.logout()
    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
    .permitAll()
```

would invalidate my `HttpSession` so that the next login would be allowed, but that is not happening.

When I look at the logs, these are the lines that are different when I log in the 2nd time:

```
s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy@2cc9f3de
w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationException: Maximum sessions of 1 for this principal exceeded
w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@16c670c3
```

.a.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler : Redirecting to /login?error

Any advice would be welcome.

My application can be found at https://github.com/arnaldop/enhanced-pet-clinic.

Here's code from my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` subclass:

```
private static final String[] UNSECURED_RESOURCE_LIST =
    new String[] {"/", "/resources/**", "/assets/**", "/css/**", "/webjars/**",
        "/images/**", "/dandelion-assets/**", "/unauthorized", "/error*"};

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(UNSECURED_RESOURCE_LIST);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //@formatter:off
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(UNSECURED_RESOURCE_LIST)
                .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/owners/**", "/vets/**", "/vets*").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/manage/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest()
                .permitAll()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()
        .and()
            .requiresChannel()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/owners/**", "/vets/**", "/vets*", "/manage/**")
                    .requiresSecure()
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/router?q=unauthorized")
        .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                .expiredUrl("/login?expired")
        ;
    //@formatter:on
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your logout is even invoked. You have both a `logoutUrl` and `logoutRequestMatcher` set, those might interfere. I would remove the latter. Also your configuration (`invalidateHttpSession` and `deleteCookies` is basically the default. Also make sure that you use the same protocol (https) to invoke the logout, http and https in general don't share sessions...

Comment: Thanks. I made the appropriate changes to the code and updated the post. Again, I appreciate any insights.

Comment: Have you registered the [`HttpSessionEventPublisher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/session/HttpSessionEventPublisher.html)? That is the component that triggers the clean up of sessions (See also http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrent-sessions. Also instead of the `logoutRequestMatcher` I suggest to simply use `logoutUrl("/logout")  `

Comment: When I switch the `logoutRequestMatcher` for `logoutUrl`, https://localhost:8443/logout returns a 404 with `Request 'GET /logout' doesn't match 'POST /logout` in the log. It seems that `logoutUrl()` only defines a POST URL.

Regarding the `HttpSessionEventPublisher`, I've tried a bunch of different ways with Spring Boot but still can't get it to compile or to behave any differently.

What is THE way to add `HttpSessionEventPublisher` to a SpringBoot application?

I'm not currently extending `SpringBootServletInitializer`. The application is an executable JAR but eventually it might be.

Comment: @M.Deinum, in addition to my previous comment, I have not found this in any sample provided with Spring Boot. `HttpSessionEventPublisher` is missing from all samples.

The key is I am trying to do this with JavaConfig and Spring Boot, no XML.

Comment: I also tried creating a class that implements `WebApplicationInitializer`, overrides `onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)` and calls `servletContext.addListener(new HttpSessionEventPublisher())`.

Again, no change. Remember that I'm trying to do this with minimal footprint so I didn't have to manually redo anything from Spring Boot that is disabled by my overriding too much of Boot's code.

Comment: A `WebApplicationInitializer` doesn't do anything in the case of Spring Boot (unless you are deploying it as a war). Just add the listener as a bean to your configuration.

Comment: Ok, that's starting to get me somewhere.

I added the code below to my main class, which extends `java.util.Object`:

`@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> getHttpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
}`

It still has no effect. Logout still doesn't invalidate the session.

- Am I adding the bean properly?
- Does my class need to be configured differently?

My class has the `@ComponentScan`, `@Configuration` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotations.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I am also struggling on how to actually register the `HttpSessionEventPublisher`, using pure java config and spring boot

Comment: In fact, I cant even get `.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1)                    .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);` to even do anything

Comment: I got this email. I haven't tested yet. It looks like this might work, though.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1537#issuecomment-55609582

Comment: I just verified the workaround in my previous comment and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had also the same problem on spring boot which I fixed it by implementing HttpSessionEventPublisher

```
// Register HttpSessionEventPublisher
    @Bean
    public static ServletListenerRegistrationBean httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }
```