# Not able to login after logged out

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to allow a user to create only one current session. In my case, it's allowing user to create only one session, but once the user is logged out, they are not able to login again.

Security configuration file:

```java
        .and()
    .csrf()
        .and()
    .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied")
        .and()
    .sessionManagement()
        .maximumSessions(1)
        .expiredUrl("/login")
        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()) ;
}

@Bean
public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    SessionRegistry sessionRegistry = new SessionRegistryImpl();
    return sessionRegistry;
}
```

Logout Controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null) {    
        new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
    }
    
    return "redirect:/login?logout";
}
```

I have tried with invalidating and destroying cookie also, still it's not working.

Comment: I am maintaining user login and logged out details in mine database for auditing purpose. That's why i need some customisation in these process.

Comment: This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486722/spring-boot-security-logout-does-not-invalidate-session/42360185

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot Security Logout Does Not Invalidate Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486722/spring-boot-security-logout-does-not-invalidate-session)