# Spring security: after log out the login doesn't work anymore if I use maxSessionsPreventsLogin()

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf

I'm using Spring Security to perform log in and log out.

Log in and log out seem to work well everytime I perform them.

If I add `maxSessionsPreventsLogin()` the log in works during the **first attempt**; after the log out, I can't log in anymore. The method `failureUrl()` is called and the user is redirect to **/login?error**

This is my configure method:

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

       httpSecurity.formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login") 
            .usernameParameter("userId") 
            .passwordParameter("password");

       httpSecurity.formLogin()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .failureUrl("/login?error") 
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);          

       httpSecurity.logout()                
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout");     

      httpSecurity.exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/login?accessDenied");  

       httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll() 
            .antMatchers("/**/add").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")    
            .antMatchers("/**/market/**").access("hasRole('USER')");            
    }
```

The **csrf** system is enabled, and accordingly to Spring Security needs I put

`<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>`

inside the login form and inside the log out form (in which I perform a **POST** request to "**/logout**")

Can anybody help me? Thank you

Comment: If you deploy your app e.g. on tomcat then your session is valid until the tomcat session management invalidates it. Therefore your session is still valid even if you've logged out.

Comment: The logout invalidates the session, unless you are hacking around the Spring Security logout mechanism. And I wonder did you register the `HttpSessionEventPublisher` which handles the session removal?

Comment: I didn't register any HttpSessionEventPublisher, I thought spring would take care of invalidating session. I'll look into HttpSessionEventPublisher. :)

Comment: @MDP  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36970658/5277820

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41429778/spring-security-logout-and-maximum-sessions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot Security Logout Does Not Invalidate Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486722/spring-boot-security-logout-does-not-invalidate-session)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to invalidate the session upon logout

```
.logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .permitAll();
```